# how to remove particular word in statement using c#

Tags: c#

I am having doubt in removing particular word in a statement.If the statement is like this

```
"Furore over care. data programme could jeopardise future medical research,  doctors and charities warnresearch:1|"
```

how can i remove `research:1|` part from  that line`?

I tried using

```
foreach( string str in datalist)
   str.split("research:1|")
```

and also `str.Replace("research:1|", "");`
Both didn't work.

Comment: Read the damn documentation

Answer (score 3):

strings are immutable, `Replace` method creates a new string instead of modifying the original one.You need to assign result back to your string:

```
str = str.Replace("research:1|", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IndexOf` or `LastIndexOf` and `Substring` or `Remove`:

```
string text = "Furore over care. data programme could jeopardise future medical research,  doctors and charities warnresearch:1|";
int lastIndex = text.LastIndexOf("research:1|");
if (lastIndex >= 0)
    text = text.Remove(lastIndex, "research:1|".Length);
```

Use `text = text.Remove(lastIndex, "research:1|".Length);` if it's not at the end.

If you want to replace all occurences you can use `String.Replace` as you've already tried. But you have to reassign the result because [strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) are immutable (cannot be changed).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you assign the result to the original string:

```
foreach( string str in datalist)
{
   str = str.Replace("research:1|", "");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, someone already gave the same response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.Remove(); in order to remove part of the string you don't want.

```
string str = "Furore over care. data programme could jeopardise future medical research,  doctors and charities warnresearch:1|";
string remove = "research:1|";

str = str.Remove(str.IndexOf(remove), remove.Length);
```